# On which programming languages can Curry-Howard's isomorphism be implemented?

Tags: functional-programming, programming-languages, computer-science

Besides from Haskell (after all, Haskell is named after Haskell Curry), or academic languages like Agda, Idris, or Coq, which of the current programming languages, specially the ones that have some real-world applications, can be used to write programs that would be isomorphic to proofs?

Comment: This is a nice question. You may have a better cache of seeing it answered at cs.stackexchange.com, I think. However, one thing that seems off to me is that the CHI is independent of the type system, so any typed (dynamically or statically, explicitly or not) language curries its (restricted form of) CHI. Procedural and OO programming languages are, however, usually "low" in the lambda cube and cannot express the first-order logic fully (i.e. they are incomplete). Maybe are you asking about a language which type system is logically complete (e.g. it has dependent types) and used in real-life?